# i Cant see my images from public folder in Laravel 5.2 from the browser

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5, virtualhost

I am just new to laravel 5.2, i was able to update the public folder to "public_html", as it is online. i then created a folder named "icons".
My website address is " www.ameenman.com, using virtualhost settings on windows and wamp as my apache/php local server.

I'm trying to access the images inside the icons folder which would be www.ameenman.com/icons/p1.jpg, but its giving me an error, the image is not displaying but rather all i see is an image placeholder because the image fails to load.

Please what could be the problem, i dont know if it is from the .htaccess file in the public folder or maybe i'm missing a line in the virtualhost settings, because i've been googling and going through different opinions and articles online but yet to no avail.

i need help please else my best option is to revert and keep using laravel 4.2 which i'm comfortable with.

the image below shows what it looks like on chrome

[image: what it looks like on my browser]

Comment: Try it using only icons/p1.png or use public_path('/icons.p1.png')

Comment: yep.. i did that. and still got the same results.. i saw nothing.

Comment: ok, next you would want to try and see if you can access it with a web browser, key in example.com/icons/p1.png on your browser's address and see if you can view it.

Comment: interesteen, i get a Forbidden,  You don't have permission to access /icons/p1.png on this server..

Comment: ok, next up, check your icons folder permission, your server user group (most likely www-data) should have read access

Comment: so what could be the problem, is the public folder protected or what? coz i've tried editing the .htaccess files and the virtualhost settings, i have laravel 4 projects setup and working very fine, but only this project is giving me issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129913/discussion-between-sted-and-andaeiii).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to call your images this way:

```
<img src="{{ asset('icons/p1.png') }}">
```

Comment: i tried this and it didnt work.... several times, i even included the url helper...  {{ URL::asset(~~ ) }} and to no avail...

Comment: You should try my code and paste the source code of the webpage after that.